# Reload div content for everyone that is online

Tags: javascript

This site does specifically what i want to do http://en.lichess.org/. Users join the chess game and after some seconds the lobby refreshes and there are new games added. Does anybody know how can i do that ? or at least give me a starting point?

Comment: A super simple way is to have a setInterval that does an ajax request to get whatever info you want, then updates the pages. The setInterval could run every 10-15 seconds, or however ofter you need it to.

Comment: @Jacques thanks for the fast answer but i just want to reload a table, just like on that website, not an entire page, and just reload it, not to add data or anything else.

Comment: The correct way to do this is either with websockets or event stream, the page you show uses websockets

Comment: I said update the page, not reload it :). You can update parts of the DOM quite easily, which is what that page is doing. An event is emitting from the websockets telling the website to update that part of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the traditional method (and for older clients) you would do 'long-polling' which would fire every few seconds asking for updates. The new way is through web sockets. The page you reference uses websockets.

So if you have a modern browser, then you can use Websockets and the server can `push` data to the browser (same with EventStream). Then that message is read on the browser and the proper view is updated.

There are some frameworks which do this stuff for you, biggest one I can think of is [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/)

See the dev console:
[image]